# MS ACCESS---Refresh all via VBA

Tags: ms-access, forms

How do I refresh all via vba?
I want to refresh all open forms...

Comment: Refresh what? Do you mean requery? It seems an unlikely thing to wish to do.

Comment: btw. it would be good-form to "accept" some of the answers to your previous questions - if they have indeed answered your question suficiently.

Answer (score 5):

The reason @CodeSlave's answer probably didn't do what you needed, is that the VBA method you need is *requery*, not refresh. Refresh will display changes made to existing records, but only requery will display newly added records.

Here is a more concise version of the code (put this in a Module, so that you can call it from any form):

```
Public Sub RequeryOpenForms()
    Dim f as Form

    For Each f In Access.Forms
        f.Requery
    Next
End Sub
```

NOTE: Unfortunately, requery has the side-effect of losing the currently selected record. This can be particularly frustrating for a use if there are a long list of records, since they may have to scroll down a long way to find the record that they were previously looking at.

Comment: Hmm. I don't like code like that. Two things: 1. any form open in design view will error out. 2. why requery forms without a recordsource? The latter won't have any effect or cause an error, but it offends my programming esthetics to do something that is of no purpose.

Comment: Thanks, what can we do to get around erroring out of any forms in design view and how do I get things back to the original view (can I bookmark first?) rather than having the form show a different record prior to the requery

Comment: You'd check the form's CurrentView property (there's an enum for the possibilities) to see if it's open in design view, and not requery if it is. If you want to return to the original current record after the requery, then you should save the PK value before the Requery and then use FindFirst to get back to it. Bookmarks do not survive a requery.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
Sub AllForms()
Dim obj As AccessObject
dim dbs As Object
Dim i As Integer
dim intFormCount as Integer

    Set dbs = Application.CurrentProject
    intFormCount  = dbs.AllForms.Count - 1

    For i = 0 To intFormCount
        If dbs.AllForms(i).isloaded = True Then
            dbs.AllForms(i).refresh
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If I add a record to one table, while a form that accesses that table is open...I'd like the new record just added to the table to be available in that form when I go back to it...so at this time, I add a record to a table, go to the form (which is actually a subform) and press refresh for that new record to be available within the form...manually it works...the above VBA did not :(

Comment: refresh <> repaint <> requery - as @ToddOwen says you probably want requery instead of refresh.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using AllForms and checking the IsLoaded property instead of just using the Forms collection (which only includes loaded forms).

Answer (score 1):

In a comment above you say:

> I'd like the new record just added to
>   the table to be available in that form
>   when I go back to it

You might want to examine the Activate event. But it bothers me to requery the form unless you know for a fact that records have been added. I expect that if I needed to do this (I've never done so, actually -- my users know about Shift-F9 where it's relevant, but most of them never need it), I'd use the OnActivate event and check the current count of records and only requery the form if the count doesn't match the current recordset.

But again, I consider it a fairly exotic thing to do. In general, it's probably an architectural error to have too many forms sitting around with an open recordset that you depart from and then come back to. They should probably be entirely closed instead of being left open when you're away from them. This reduces the number of table handles, as well as the number of locks held on the back end database, both of which can be problems if not properly managed.

Comment: Yep. That's the way I'd see it as well. I cannot think of an occasion where I have needed to requery all open forms. Also, I try to avoid more than one or two open forms.

Comment: @Christopher Robinson It occurs to me that you may have used Form B to add a record to Form A and perhaps missed requerying Form A at that point.

Comment: If the Form A/B architecture is in place, B should be opened with the dialog switch so you can requery A after B is closed.